# ajax loading gif in tab panel

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to show a gif during an Ajax call; it works fine if the div is at the body level but won't appear in a tab panel. I've tried putting the div at the tab-pane, container, row and column levels but it won't show.
Simple html:

```
 <div id="loading">
     <img id="loading-image" src="images/page-loader.gif" alt="waiting..." />
 </div>
```

jquery:

```
$('#loading').hide(); $('#loading').show(); // as required
```

css:

```
#loading {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 position: fixed;
 display: block;
 opacity: 0.7;
 background-color: #fff;
 z-index: 99;
 text-align: center;
}

#loading-image {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 left: 24px;
 z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $('<div id="loading"><img id="loading-image" src="images/page-loader.gif" alt="waiting..." /></img></div>')
.prependTo('.tabClass'); });

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    $('#loading').remove();
});
```

replacing 'tabClass' with the class of whatever container you want the gif animation to attach to.

I've found this solution to be cleaner & work well.

Comment: Thanks, agentb26, but can you check this in some way? If I use remove() on the element '#loading', the gif never disappears. If I add a class to the new div and remove() the class it does disappear correctly but I am (almost)back where I started; the gif shows first time but never again. Oddly, though, if I just use 'onclick' events to show and hide the gif (using the same 'prependto' method) it works fine - it appears to be some problem associating it with the ajax call. (btw there is a typo error at the end of your <div><img> ordering.)

Comment: Sorry I fixed the typo. That seems weird - I use this exact code and my .gif continually appears/disappears when I make ajax calls ($.getJSON and $.ajax). Are you using jQuery ajax calls?

Comment: Yes, jquery ajax. But just discovered a difference with the ajax call that 'works' and the one that doesn't. The non-working one was a synchronous call (for reasons I won't go into here); restructuring the code a little to make it async makes the gif appear as expected. So, I assume the DOM didn't have time to display the gif because it was busy waiting for the ajax call to finish...and when it did, of course, the gif was hidden again straight away! Knowing this, I think my original method would work as well but yours is neater, thanks.